# Can DBIx::Class be used to create tables?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I do not think I understand the scope of `DBIx::Class`
Do I have to manually create a database with regular SQL first, then use the schemaloader (or manually code the schema/resultsets)?
Or is there a way to tell `DBIx::Class` to go ahead and create the tables from a manually coded schema and resultset?
I ask b/c if I need to create the database via SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement, I have the column essentially duplicated in the ResultSet code, OR I need to rely on schemaloader which I assume is inefficient and inappropriate for production.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can [`deploy()`](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/DBIx-Class-0.08202/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm#deploy) your schema:

```
my $schema = MyApp::Schema->connect(
          $dsn,
          $user,
          $password,
        );
$schema->deploy( { add_drop_table => 1 } );
```

Of course, the above will drop your existing tables :)

Answer (score 10):

You can go either route. You can create a schema and get [DBIx::Class to analyse it](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/DBIx-Class-0.08202/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Features.pod#Schema%3a%3aLoader), or you can get DBIx::Class to [build the schema to you](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/DBIx-Class-0.08202/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Features.pod#-%3Edeploy).

The former does not have to be inefficient for production, since you can get DBIx::Class to [save the generated code](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07033/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm#dump_directory) so that it doesn't have to do the analysis every run.